# Converting projection/ reprojecting EPSG:32651 to EPSG:4326 in OpenLayers 7.1

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

My points data (hull) is in EPSG:32651, i want my output to be in EPSG:4326 so that it will display on my map. How will I do it. I've seen some similar question but they are using version 3.x. I'm guessing its different on 7.x.

```
 var vectorSource3 = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            })).readFeatures(hull)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as in version 3 you will need to define the EPSG:32651 projection and specify the data and display projections when parsing the data.  The only change is you must now register proj4 after the defining the projection

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:32651','+proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

 var vectorSource3 = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
            })).readFeatures(hull, {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:32651',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            })
        });
```